# Envio de dados do formulário com Ajax para o PHP e cadastramento no banco de dados não funcionando

Tags: php, ajax, formulário

Boa tarde pessoal.
Tenho um formulário onde envio os dados para uma página php que insere esses dados no banco de dados e também os envia para um email. A página é atualizada no final. Até aí tudo certo.

Mas, gostaria que a página não fosse atualizada, então utilizei ajax pra fazer isso. Porém, quando coloco o ajax, ele aparentemente envia os dados para a página php e exibe uma div oculta com uma mensagem de sucesso. Porém o email não é enviado e os dados não são cadastrados no banco de dados.

Podem me ajudar com isso?

Seguem os códigos:

Meu formulário na página index.php:

```
<div>
                            <form id="contato-form" method="post" action="enviar.php" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <h3 class="h3-title" style="font-weight: 900;">Vamos trabalhar juntos?<br />
                                    Queremos conversar com você.</h3>
                                <div class="inputBox-contato">
                                    <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($data['nome'])){ echo $data['nome']; } ?>" required="required" onkeyup="corrigirValor(this)">
                                    <span>Qual o seu nome completo?</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inputBox-contato">
                                    <input name="telefone" id="telefone" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($data['telefone'])){ echo $data['telefone']; } ?>" required="required" onkeyup="handlePhone(event)" maxlength="15">
                                    <span>E seu número de whatsapp?</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inputBox-contato">
                                    <input name="valor" id="valor" type="currency" value="<?php if (isset($data['valor'])){ echo $data['valor']; } ?>" required="required">
                                    <span>Qual o valor mensal da sua fatura de energia?</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inputBox-contato">
                                    <input name="descricao" id="descricao" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($data['descricao'])){ echo $data['descricao']; } ?>" required="required">
                                    <span>Descreva o seu projeto.</span>
                                </div>

                                <br />
                                    <label for="anexo" class="file-label2">
                                        <div>
                                            <span class="file-span2 nomedoarquivo" style="pointer-events: all;">Envie uma foto ou PDF da sua fatura de energia mais recente.</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="text-align: right">
                                            <i class="fa-solid fa-file-arrow-up icon-upload-input"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                    <input name="anexo" id="anexo" class="file-input2" type="file">

                                <br />

                                <div style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    <button class="ai-button" id="submitbtn" onclick="SubmeterFormulario('contato-form')" name="SendAddMsg" value="Enviar" style="font-size: .8em; cursor: pointer">Enviar <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-to-bracket" style="padding-left: 5px"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                            <div class="success"><p class="p-small">Enviado com sucesso!</p></div>

                        </div>
```

O ajax:

```
function SubmeterFormulario() {
            $("#contato-form").on("submit", function (e) {
                let frm = $('#contato-form');
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: frm.attr('method'),
                    url: frm.attr('action'),
                    data: frm.serialize(),

                    success: function (i) {
                        $('.success').addClass('isactive');
                        console.log('Sucesso no ajax');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Erro no ajax');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

Minha página enviar.php que recebe os dados, salva no BD e envia por email:

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

include_once './connection.php';

//Load Composer's autoloader
require './lib/vendor/autoload.php';

$data = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
    if (!empty($data['SendAddMsg'])){
        $anexo = $_FILES['anexo'];
//        var_dump($data);
//        var_dump($anexo);

        $inserir = "INSERT INTO contatos (nome, telefone, valor, descricao, file, created) VALUES (:nome, :telefone, :valor, :descricao, :file, NOW())";
        $add_contato = $conn->prepare($inserir);

        $add_contato->bindParam(':nome', $data['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_contato->bindParam(':telefone', $data['telefone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_contato->bindParam(':valor', $data['valor'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_contato->bindParam(':descricao', $data['descricao'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $add_contato->bindParam(':file', $anexo['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $add_contato->execute();

        if ($add_contato->rowCount()){
            //echo "Cadastrado com sucesso.";
            //Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            try {
                //Server settings
                //$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
                $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
                $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
                $mail->Host       = 'smtp.titan.email';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Username   = 'dados@daempresa.com.br';            //SMTP username
                $mail->Password   = 'PASSWORD';                         //SMTP password
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
                $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

                //Recipients
                $mail->setFrom('dados@daempresa.com.br', 'Dados do formulário de contato do site');
                $mail->addAddress('atendimento@santafesolar.com.br', 'Atendimento');     //Add a recipient

                //Attachments
                if (isset($anexo['name']) AND !empty($anexo['name'])) {
                    $mail->addAttachment($anexo['tmp_name'], $anexo['name']);    //Optional name
                }

                //Content
                $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = 'Dados recebidos via formulário de contato do site Santa Fé Solar';
                $mail->Body    = "<h3 style='font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 1.2em; color: #232323'>Dados recebidos via formulário de contato do site Santa Fé Solar.</h3>
                                    <br /><p style='font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 0.9em'>Nome: <span style='font-weight: 300'>" . $data['nome'] . "</span></p>" .
                                    "<p style='font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 0.9em'>Telefone: <span style='font-weight: 300'>" . $data['telefone'] ."</span></p>" .
                                    "<p style='font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 0.9em'>Valor médio da conta: <span style='font-weight: 300'>" . $data['valor'] ."</span></p>" .
                                    "<p style='font-family: Poppins, sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 0.9em'>Descrição: <span style='font-weight: 300'>" . $data['descricao'] . "</span></p>";
                $mail->AltBody = 'Por favor, acesse um aplicativo atualizado para ler este email.';

                $mail->send();

                echo 'Enviado com sucesso.';
                unset($data);

                if (isset($anexo['name']) AND (!empty($anexo['name']))){
                    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
                    $directory = 'uploads/' . $last_id . "/";
                    mkdir($directory, 0755);
                    move_uploaded_file($anexo['tmp_name'], $directory .$anexo['name']);
                }

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "A mensagem não pôde ser enviada.";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Falha no cadastro no banco de dados.";
        }
    }
```

O site está no ar, caso queiram ver "ao vivo", rs. Segue:
https://www.santafesolar.com.br/contato

Answer (score -2):

Saudações amigo, no action do form no html, coloca o caminho num todo com o https, e não  apenas o  nome  do arquivo.

Ex: substituir contato.php por https://localhost/contato.php
Verifica isso e tenta novamente.

Faça isso, abra o console do inspecionar elemento no navegador, e verifique o log se há algum erro!

Comment: Olá Wallace. Obrigado pela disponibilidade em ajudar.
Alterei, mas o resultado foi o mesmo. No inspecionar retorna a mensagem de sucesso do ajax: "Sucesso no ajax."

Comment: pelo contrário, nunca se deve colocar o caminho relativo do arquivo, pois quando você vai publicar esse conteúdo o caminho relativo muda, o certo é funciona apenas com o "contato.php"

Comment: Então Gabriel, está dessa forma mesmo. Aparentemente está tudo certo. Não consigo encontrar onde possa estar o erro pra não estar enviando o email e salvando no banco de dados... Sou iniciante também, posso estar deixando passar alguma coisa bem óbvia, mas... não sei o que possa estar ocorrendo. Se puder por favor analisar os códigos que postei, agradeço demais.

Comment: @gabrielfalieri, você deve sim colocar o caminho, mas não escrever ele, e sim utilizar uma constante que irá trocar em modo de Produção e Desenvolvimento! Leia mais sobre URL Amigável, sobre padrões de PROJETO e verá que é NECESSÁRIO! Cuidado ao falar o contrário sem saber.